# Graceful Shutdown of Thread executing native code

Tags: java, multithreading, native, macos-carbon

In my application, I have a `ExecutorService` of fixed size `1`.

Now the thread calls some native code. Inside the native method, it gets blocked and waits for the OS events which needs to be dispatched. The issue is in graceful shutdown of the `ExecutorService`.

If I interrupt the thread, then thread still doesn't come out (Obviously). If I set the thread as `daemon`. Still it doesn't let the JVM to shutdown. The only working code I have is using `System.exit` which for obvious reason I do not intend to use. Any other way out?

Comment: Do you think try catch and end normal will work?

Comment: @Madhu You can't throw an Exception (i.e try/catch anything) if it's stuck in native code - that's the problem.

Comment: What native call is blocking?  Can you artificially satisfy the wait?

Comment: 'The only working code I have is using System.exit' What is the overriding reason for not using System.exit?

Comment: @MartinJames Its a call to Mac Carbon framework function called `ReceiveNextEvent` which keeps dispatching OS events. The issue with System.exit is that- Firstly I need to free some native resources, and that can only I happen if I move out of native code.

Comment: Oh - dunno Mac Carbon :((  Can't you, like, queue up an OS event?

Comment: Ha, so did I. But I think progressed well except here. Queue up? I dont think it will solve the purpose as I need to dispatch the events and take necessary actions (which is currently happening) spontaneosly without delay. Issue is only with shutting it down.

Answer (score 3):

The error lies in the native code that doesn't return, really. The only way to do it through the higher level java, as far as I know, is to [`stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) the thread - which is deprecated for [several reasons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

To do this, you'd need to redesign to use an old-fashioned `Thread` instead of `ExecutorService`. You might as well do that as the size is fixed at 1 and therefore `ExecutorService` won't give you many advantages. As far as I see from your question it might seem like a viable option for you to use `stop()` if you do not keep any locks in the thread when you `stop()` it.

Edit:

According to [Apple's developer guide](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon_Event_Manager/CarbonEvents.pdf) (page 47), you can specify an `EventTimeout` when calling `ReceiveNextEvent`:

> ReceiveNextEvent runs the low-level event loop, placing events as they
>   occur into the event queue. The function returns when an event you
>   specified occurs, **or when the specified timeout is exceeded**.
>
> ```
> OSStatus ReceiveNextEvent(
> UInt32 inNumTypes,
> const EventTypeSpec *inList,
> EventTimeout inTimeout,
> Boolean inPullEvent,
> EventRef *outEvent);
> ```

So, if I understand correctly setting a timeout when calling the native code will do the trick for you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Thread.stop` only. An error. The thread doesn't come out and no ThreadDeath exception is thrown